# MySql query to pull data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have two tables table1 and table2. I want get yearwise distribution of the topics. I made a second table for topic data. I have created random tables, table1 and table2.

```
tabel1

id | year
1  | 2001
2  | 2003
3  | 2001
4  | 2002
5  | 2001
```

I have second table with shared "id"

```
table2

id | topic | subtopic
1  | sport | volley 
1  | water | ok
1  | stock | apple
2  | stock | us 
2  | stock | pine
3  | world | uk
3  | water | salt
4  | water | sweet
4  | world | ep
5  | sport | volley
5  | stock | apple
5  | stock | pine
```

TOP categories for topic are stock(3=1,2,5), water(3=1,3,4), sport(2=1,5), world(2=2,4)

And, lets say I want only top two "topic" data so, my output data would be

```
     stock | water
    ----------------
2001    2  |  2
2002    0  |  1
2003    1  |  0
```

So far,I have managed to do it for individual topic

```
SELECT table1.year AS YEAR, COUNT(DISTINCT table2.id ) AS lcount
FROM table1, table2
WHERE topic = 'stock'
AND table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY YEAR
```

Topics are not limited to only 4, there can be n-different topics. So, n-different topics are to be found. I need pick top 2 from them.

Comment: And the code you have tried so far is? ..

Comment: This looks like a job for group by and having clauses. you should look into those.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a built-in pivot operator, so you can't create a pivot table unless you know beforehand which columns you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get your result:

```
select t1.year,
  count(distinct case when topic = 'stock' then t2.id end) stock,
  count(distinct case when topic = 'water' then t2.id end) water,
  count(distinct case when topic = 'sport' then t2.id end) sport,
  count(distinct case when topic = 'world' then t2.id end) world
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.year;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0754e/2).

If you have an unknown number of values or unknown topics that will be returned, then you will have to use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(distinct CASE WHEN topic = ''',
      topic,
      ''' THEN t2.id END) AS `',
      topic, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
(
  select count(distinct id) total, topic
  from table2 
  group by topic
  order by total desc
  limit 2
) d;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT t1.year, ', @sql, ' 
            from table1 t1
            left join table2 t2
              on t1.id = t2.id
            group by t1.year');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0754e/27)

Comment: stock(3=1,2,5), water(3=1,3,4), sport(2=1,5), world(2=2,4) are to be determined automatically. Topics are not limited to only 4, there can be n-different topics. I need pick top 2 from them.

Comment: @JohnGalt I edited my answer to include a dynamic sql version.

Comment: Result is coming as (SPORT, WATER) but it should be  (stock | water) right?

Comment: SQL Fiddle solution is perfect. I tried to recreate this in wamp phpmyadmin and getting an error: #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE! Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.`year`,
    COALESCE(b_stock.rec_count, 0) as `stock`,
    COALESCE(b_water.rec_count, 0) as `water`
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b2.`year`, COUNT(b.*) as rec_count
    FROM table2 b
    JOIN table1 b2 ON b2.id = b.id
    WHERE b.topic = 'stock'
    GROUP BY b2.year
) b_stock ON b_stock.`year` = a.`year` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b2.`year`, COUNT(b.*) as rec_count
    FROM table2 b
    JOIN table1 b2 ON b2.id = b.id
    WHERE b.topic = 'water'
    GROUP BY b2.year
) b_water ON b_water.`year` = a.`year`
GROUP BY a.`year`
ORDER BY a.`year`
```

Comment: I need to determine 'stock' and 'water' are top 2 topics also automatically.

Comment: @JohnGalt how many different types of topics will you have? If you will only ever have a handful, you can add a few additional joins to get the counts for all topics in one query, and from that point, you can see which ones are the top topic by using ORDER BY.